offer price with target ROI
So I'm trying to do an offer price algorithm.
A1: asking price: 85000
A2: Total Revenue: $15,300
A3: Target ROI: 20%
A4: 8500 (A1 - X) (reduction price)
A5: Formula: offer price is : X
X = 76500 (trial and error using (A2/A5) to get 20% ROI)
How do I value X if I only have values A1-A3?
Any help would be appreciated,

What is A5? A Fudge Factor?

This is a math question, not a programming question, but X = A2/A3.  (15300 / 0.2 => 76500)  And you never mention what is in A5, but you have two different items in A4

I see you have edited your question to clarify A5.  As I wrote above:  A5: = A2/A3

As I wrote in my comment, this is a math question.
But for your computation: x = A2/A3
or:  76500 = 15300/20%
